# Can I setup DNS server on my server with dynamic ip ?

Tags: domain-name-system, nameserver

I bought recently a domain and I want to point it to my server. The provider ask me for `name servers`.

I am aware I need a DNS server and set-up `name servers` but I don't know if it will work with dynamic IP.

My Internet provider offers a service named `Dynamic DNS` where I can create a little subdomain to point my `IP Address`.

I want to set-up this server for my little projects, some databases a website or two etc...

I'm running latest Ubuntu Server. Is there any alternative or solution for this problem ?

Best

Comment: That's a very bad idea, use your registrars name servers. If they don't have any then use a DNS provider service.

Comment: Can you give me an example of a good DNS provider service or where can I read more about this ?

Comment: I've used godaddy in the past to buy domains, and just recently switched to google.  Both (and from what I've seen elsewhere, just about any registrar) will act as your primary/secondary name servers.  What I'd do is set up CNAME records from yourdomain.com to your.sub.domain.from.isp.com and let your service provided keep the your.sub.domain.from.isp.com in synch with your actual IP.